# Получить настройки прокси

Tags: winapi, прокси, proxy, c++

Добрый день! Понадобилось получить дефолтовые настройки прокси в Windows XP. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO proxy;
if (WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration(&proxy)==false){
    cout << "fail" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

При сборке получаю сообщение:

```
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/oim/Мои документы/NetBeansProjects/ProxyEnabler/main.cpp:46: undefined reference to `_WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/aa384095(v=vs.85).aspx
нужно залинковать Winhttp.lib (см. в конце страницы)

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, не прицепилась библиотека в параметрах среды.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <wininet.h>

INTERNET_PROXY_INFO proxy;
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(proxy);
if (InternetQueryOption( 0, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, &proxy, &dwSize) ) {
   proxy.dwAccessType;
   proxy.lpszProxy;
   proxy.lpszProxyBypass;
   };
```